# Limits of Power Series

Tags: limits, power-series

I need to solve the following:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \displaystyle \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{x^n}{n!}}
$$

The answer given is  $-1$.

Please advise on the initial steps to proceed, I am stuck because I know that $\sum(AB)\ne \sum(A)\sum(B)$ and $\sum\frac{A}{B}\ne\frac{\sum A}{\sum B}$, hence there is nothing much I can do with the expression.

Comment: The first term of the numerator is $-x^2/2$. The first term of the denominator is $x^2/2$.

Comment: but $\frac{\sum A}{\sum B} \ne \sum \frac{A}{B}$ so I do not see how the terms in $x^2$ can cancel out.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^2/2+O(x^3)}{x^2/2+O(x^3)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1+O(x)}{1+O(x)}=\color{red}{-1}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{e^{x}-x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-\sin x}{e^{x}-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-\cos x}{e^{x}}=-1.
\end{align*}
Perhaps,
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-x^{2}/2!+x^{4}/4!-\cdots}{x^{2}/2!+x^{3}/3!+\cdots}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{x^{-2}(-x^{2}/2!+x^{4}/4!-\cdots)}{x^{-2}(x^{2}/2!+x^{3}/3!+\cdots)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-1/2!+x^{2}/4!-\cdots}{1/2!+x/3!+\cdots}\\
&=\dfrac{-1/2}{1/2}\\
&=-1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, but the question requires that I solve the power series and lHopitals Rule is not allowed.

Comment: You can cancel upside down the factor $x^{2}$.

Comment: But $\frac {\sum A}{\sum B} \ne \sum \frac{A}{B}$, so I do not see how I can cancel the term in $x^2$.

Comment: @NetUser5y62: The main term of the numerator and denominator involves $x^2$. All other terms in the power series are "insignificant" (in a sense).

Comment: See @Jack D'Aurizio's comment above for clarification of my comment.